# Getting garbage content from httpwebrequest in c#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I am trying to read the response content of `HttpWebRequest` using `HtmlAgilityPack` but somehow it is showing garbage or some other encoded characters, Please help me how can I read the content

The content which I am getting is:

> "\u001f‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0í½\a\u001cI–%&/mÊ{\u007fJõJ×àt¡\b€`\u0013$Ø\u0090@\u0010ìÁˆÍæ’ì\u001diG#)«*\u0081ÊeVe]f\u0016@Ìí\u009d¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;\u009dN'÷ßÿ?\fd\u0001löÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ\u001f?~|\u001f?\"~ãÇ¿ëÓ/OÞü>/OÓy»(Ó—*=y~v’~´}÷îwï\u009dÜ½ûôÍÓô÷þö›/ž§»ã\u009dôM\u009d-›¢-ªeVÞ½{úâ£ô£yÛ®\u001eÝ½{uu5¾º7®ê‹»o^Ý}\aX»xY\u007fÝn½7Ç³vöÑÑc|‘¾[”Ëæ³\b”Ý‡\u000f\u001fÊË\u001f¡Ñ£2[^|öÑ·O?Jío\u0004\"ÏfG\u008fËbù6­óò³\u008f\u0016Ù²8Ï›ö£t^ççŸ}t×|0þé¦Z~”Þ=z¼ÈÛŒ†Ú®¶ó*´..?ûè¤Z¶ù²Ý~s½Ê?J§ò×g\u001fµù»ö.º?L§ó¬nòö³u{¾}°\u0019ÈsÂm\u009d]ø€\bÑè+¿÷öWÇÛ'Õb•µÅ¤ôß8;ý,Ÿ]ä£é¼®\u0016ùg»îýeF\u007f\u007f´h²Õª,¦ôbµÜ¦×Î‹\vïõeµÌ?¢7\u001cYšyU·Óu›\u0016ÔÈÒæ<»Äßcúç£´¥Ñ\u007föQ±
>   Üï¾Û¦\u008f¨\u001dÁh¦u±jõ[&ÉOg—™|úÑÑo|™Õéwèƒ×üÁWM^ƒ\u0010uU>É.ÒÏÒ­óõr\n$Ó­;é/æÖÓª,sùì³t™_¥_N~šþÞºsø\u001b·ó¢\u0019g³\u0019}áÞ+f£´ÂËÅyºå^\u001eÏ³æË«åËºZåu{MÍî QK\u0014»J?2\u001f§Å,ýÞGé'øùIúÑ÷Ó¬,kb™ë4\u007fW4m“\u0016ËAô?:ü\u008d\u007fÉoì:ü^1û>!VáSF´Î\u0017ÕeN\u001fù¸\u0002\a

my code

```
                HttpWebRequest requestTransaction;
                Uri uriTransact = new Uri(Url);
                requestTransaction = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriTransact);
                requestTransaction.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                requestTransaction.Method = "Post";
                requestTransaction.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                requestTransaction.KeepAlive = true;
                requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                requestTransaction.CookieContainer = cookies;
                requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
                requestTransaction.Host = host;
                requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Origin", requestOrigin);
                requestTransaction.Referer = requestReferer
                requestTransaction.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";


                byte[] sentData2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData2);
                requestTransaction.ContentLength = sentData2.Length;
                using (System.IO.Stream sendStream = requestTransaction.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    sendStream.Write(sentData2, 0, sentData2.Length);
                    sendStream.Close();
                }
                 using (var response = requestTransaction.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                }
```

After this on checking `doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml` i am getting the above content.

Comment: Are you sure `Encoding.UTF8` is the correct encoding?

Comment: Yes, because I am using 3 more API's and the same code is working on them.

Comment: this symbol `\u001f` is UTF-16

Comment: So, how can i get the required html content from that?

Comment: Use `UTF16 encoding` as we are recommending.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out that the response was compressed.  You can either remove the

```
requestTransaction.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
```

not too sure about the br or you can add

```
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

to your HttpWebRequest, which as the name suggests, will automatically decompress the response.